# how can i get quickkey after upload file into mediafire?

Tags: php, api, cloud, mediafire

```
Array
(
    [result] => 0
    [status] => 6
    [description] => Waiting for verification
    [fileerror] => 
    [quickkey] => 
    [hash] => 
    [filename] => 
    [size] => 
    [created] => 
    [revision] => 
    [resumable_upload] => 
    [result_message] => Success
    [fileerror_message] => 
)
```

**I am using mediafire php api for upload file. Sometime in response i am getting waiting for verification. what can i do in this cases. issue on response other all thing correctly done like file upload on server, crating new folder etc.**